# CodeIgniter 2.0 DB result to array?

Tags: arrays

Here's my model

```
function getGHG(){

    $sql = "SELECT t.comp_sector as sectors, s.comp_envi_sus_energy_year as years, SUM(s.comp_envi_sus_energy_consumption) as Consumption
                FROM site_comp_envi_sus_energy s
                INNER JOIN site_comp t ON s.comp_id = t.comp_id
                WHERE t.comp_sector != ''
                GROUP BY t.comp_sector, s.comp_envi_sus_energy_year;";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($query -> num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result_array();          

    }

    else{
        echo 'Unable to retrieve GHG data.';
    }

}
```

Here's my usage in controller:

```
$chart = $this->chartmodel->getGHG();
$this->maani_xml_swf_charts->chart_data(
                                            $chart->years,
                                            $chart->sectors);
```

I want the $chart->years and $chart->sectors to be of type array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple results from your query use the $query->result_array();

however this will return an array of rows (in array format) e.g.

```
$return_array[0] = array('years' => '5', 'sectors' => '3');
$return_array[1] = array('years' => '1', 'sectors' => '2');
```

If you want to return a single row from your query as an array you use;

$query->row_array();

Which will produce the following;

$return_array['years'] = 4;
$return_array['sectors'] = 3;

See this documentation to help 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html